# Issue with shell_exec() and screen

Tags: 16.04

In my website I have sth like this:

shell_exec('cd /home/bot_'.$_SESSION['user'].' && ./run.sh daemon start');

and it works and bot is starting but I need online status on site and when I am running this command I do not have this screen shown:

if (!empty(shell_exec("sudo screen -list | grep bot_".$_SESSION['user']."_1"))) {

Command ./run.sh daemon start is adding screens:
bot_".$_SESSION['user']."*daemon and bot*".$_SESSION['user']."_1

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: status when screen is running and when it is not

Comment: to extend: I am starting screen by www and it is not shown in screen -ls

Comment: Could it be a problem that `sudo screen` does not run with root permissions, as you have nowhere to put the password, for example?

Comment: I don't think so because I execute this command: echo 'www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

Comment: Problem has been solved.
Error was in run.sh file.
Screen was starting without sudo.